# Docker: Win container: The application to execute does not exist

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-for-windows

I am trying to create my first docker image and container.
I follow documents / videos I found online.
On my `Microsoft Windows 10 Pro - 10.0.16299 Build 16299` I can successfully build ASP.NET Core application after running command `docker build -t web .`.
But when I try to run image `docker run -ti web`, I get error:

> The application to execute does not exist: 'C:\app\Web.dll'

Is there any command to list files? I want to check path and where (if) dll exists. I couldn't find such command on web.
Also any hint where to look for problem would be awesome. Also (if it helps) `docker ps` doesn't list anything.

Docker:

```
Client:
Version: 18.02.0-ce
API version: 1.36
Go version: go1.9.3
Git commit: fc4de44
Built: Wed Feb 7 21:12:53 2018
OS/Arch: windows/amd64
Experimental: false
Orchestrator: swarm

Server:
Engine:
Version: 18.02.0-ce
API version: 1.36 (minimum version 1.24)
Go version: go1.9.3
Git commit: fc4de44
Built: Wed Feb 7 21:26:24 2018
OS/Arch: windows/amd64
Experimental: true
```

Dockerfile:

```
# Stage 1
FROM microsoft/aspnetcore-build AS builder
WORKDIR /source

# caches restore result by copying csproj file separately
COPY Web.sln ./src/aspdocker/Web.sln

COPY Web.Library/Web.Library.csproj ./src/aspdocker/Web.Library/
COPY Web.Core/Web.Core.csproj ./src/aspdocker/Web.Core/
COPY Web.Hosting/Web.Hosting.csproj ./src/aspdocker/Web.Hosting/
COPY Web.Library.Tests/Web.Library.Tests.csproj ./src/aspdocker/Web.Library.Tests/
COPY Web.Core.Tests/Web.Core.Tests.csproj ./src/aspdocker/Web.Core.Tests/

# caches restore result by copying csproj file separately
RUN dotnet restore ./src/aspdocker/Web.sln

# copies the rest of your code
COPY . .

RUN dotnet publish --output /app/


# Stage 2
#FROM microsoft/aspnetcore:1.1.2
FROM microsoft/aspnetcore
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=builder /app .
#EXPOSE 5000/tcp
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Web.dll"]
```

Comment: So did you verify that your DLL is in fact exists in that path?

Comment: @GregorySuvalian I don't know how to check that. How to view files in container image?

Comment: Login into running image with `docker exec -it <imagename> powershell` and then do what you usually do

Comment: @GregorySuvalian he cannot exec into a running container because his container would be exiting immediately with the error.

@Makla run your container by overriding the default entrypoint.
`docker run -it <imagename> powershell`. Then you can check from the resulting command line if your files are present.

Also check if the Web.dll is in fact in the `/app` folder. Is it possible it is in a subfolder? In that case you may need to give the correct path relative to your WORKDIR

Comment: I run `docker build --pull -t web .` and then `docker run -it web powershell` and get the same error.

Comment: Check that the Web.dll in ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Web.dll"] actually matches the assembly name output from the ASP.Net Core project. In my case the name of the assembly differed from the project name, resulting in the same "The application to execute does not exist" error. Correcting the ENTRYPOINT in the Dockerfile and re-publishing resolved it for me.